# SwiftでmacOSの「ネットワーク環境」の名前を取得する方法

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

SwiftでmacOS上で動作するアプリを製作しています。

そこに画像[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k2Km.png)に示した赤枠の部分である、現在選択されている「ネットワーク環境」の名称を取得したいです。

SSIDの取得は以下のコードで取得できました。

```
import CoreWLAN

let SSID_Name : String = {
    return CWWiFiClient()?.interface(withName: nil)?.ssid() ?? ""
}()
```

以上のようなコードで試行錯誤をしてみましたが、わかりませんでした。

ネットで探してもそれらしい情報が見つかりません。
何か方法がありましたら、ご教示願いたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: ネットワーク環境の名称を取得したい]

Answer (score 2):

実際の情報はこちらにあるようです。

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

SystemConfigurationで調べてみると、いくつかAppleの公式ドキュメントが見つかります。

[System Configuration Programming Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_RevHistory/SC_RevHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001065-CH211-BAJDAJDJ)

API Reference [SystemConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration)

[SCNetworkConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration/1655031-scnetworkconfiguration)

preferences.plistの中では`Sets`なんてところに実際のデータがあったので、ここら辺が怪しそうです。

> Configuring Network Sets
>
> [`func SCNetworkSetCopyAll(SCPreferences)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration/1517220-scnetworksetcopyall) 
>   Returns all available sets for the specified preferences session.

他のAPI関数も試行錯誤で試してみると、こんなコードでうちのMac(10.11.5)のネットワーク環境(Location:)の名称が取得できました。

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

//デフォルトのシステム設定(SCPreferences)を取得する
let prefs = SCPreferencesCreate(nil, "process-name" as CFString, nil)!
//システム設定から[SCNetworkSet]を取得する
if let sets = SCNetworkSetCopyAll(prefs) as? [SCNetworkSet] {
    for set in sets {
        //SCNetworkSetからユーザ定義名称を取得する
        let userDefinedName = SCNetworkSetGetName(set) as String?
        print(userDefinedName ?? "*no name*")
    }
} else {
    print("cannot get [SCNetworkSet] from this preference: \(prefs)")
}
```

SandBox環境ではどうなるのかまでは試していませんが、以上ご参考までに。